# Django throws an error on any command: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv, pythonanywhere

I deployed my Django app to PythonAnywhere. I need to run some commands in their Console. I created virtual environment using command:

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 venv
```

Then I installed all my dependencies (including Django)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After, I want to migrate my database using command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get this traceback:

```
 File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/home/mkwiatek770/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 201, in get_connection_params
    if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

By the way it's happeninng on each django comand like `python manage.py flush` etc ..

Any Ideas. Thanks in advance

Edit, thats my DATABASE configuration in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get("APO_DB_NAME"),
        'USER': os.environ.get("APO_DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("APO_DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': os.environ.get("APO_DB_HOST"),
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
        'TEST': {
        },
    }
}

if os.environ.get("COGNITO_PRODUCTION"):
    DATABASES["default"]["TEST"]["NAME"] = os.environ.get("APO_DB_TEST_NAME")
```

I set all environment variables in wsgi.py file. APO_DB_HOST is also set.

Comment: looks like you haven't set a `HOST` in your database settings

Comment: I edited the post, Could you take a look if there is no mistake ?

Comment: so you have the HOST as `os.environ.get("APO_DB_HOST")` - that will be `None` if you haven't set the appropriate environment variable. So it looks like you need to set that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an environment variable, similar to this:

```
$ export APO_DB_HOST=localhost
```